# Calling java code that doesn't accept null from kotlin

Tags: kotlin, nullable

IDEA Community 2017.1.2, JRE 1.8, Kotlin 1.1.2-2

I have Java methods, located in libGdx that don't have any annotations regarding their nullability, e.g.:

```
public void render (final RenderableProvider renderableProvider) {
  renderableProvider.getRenderables(renderables, renderablesPool);
```

as we can see, argument can't be null. However, since nothing tells that it's not-null argument, Kotlin will happily pass null in `RenderableProvider?`. How do I tell Kotlin to check during compile-time that I should be passing `RenderableProvider` and not `RenderableProvider?`?

I've read about [external annotations](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/using-external-annotations/), however there is no "Specify Custom Kotlin Signature" and if I annotate `renderableProvider` as `@NotNull` nothing changes - kotlin still allows  null.

I even tried to replace `org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull` with `javax.annotation.Nonnull` in XML manually, but it makes no difference - code compiles and crashes with NPE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

External annotations are [no longer supported](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-to-use-kotlin-jdk-annotations/1384/2?u=cbruegg). You'll either have to fork libgdx and annotate the methods there or live with this issue, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap it in an extension function and then only use that for rendering:

```
fun RenderClass.renderSafe(renderProvider: RenderableProvider) = 
    this.render(renderProvider)
```

Now you can't pass `null`.