# Kotlin Scoping functions - are there any side-effects from NOT using "it" or "this"?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, syntax

Basically what is the difference between this:

```
obj?.let{ doSomethingWith(it) }
```

And this?

```
obj?.let{ doSomethingWith(obj) }
```

Obviously the first one is preferred just by reading the Kotlin docs, however I found code like the second one, and my IDE doesn't complain about it. Are there any "gotchas" to be aware of, should I always use "it" and "this" even though I'm not forced to?

Comment: Second case is not null safe if `object` is a mutable `var`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually not related that much to scoping functions, but more about null-safety.

In case `obj` (`object` is not a good name, since it's a keyword in Kotlin) is a value, this code will produce unnecessary smart cast:

```
val obj: String? = null

obj?.let {
    doSomethingWith(obj) // Smart cast to kotlin.String
}
```

In case `obj` is a variable, this becomes even worse, as was correctly pointed out in the comments, as this code may not be thread-safe anymore.

This is safe, though:

```
obj?.let { 
    doSomethingWith(it) 
}
```

Since `it` is a value, hence immutable.

Comment: Ah, ok. So "it" is guaranteed to remain non-null after nullability check. FYI, my IDE wasn't complaining because function doSomethingWith() was java code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43827706/calling-java-code-that-doesnt-accept-null-from-kotlin